# Bash : Configuring email-provider for bash-script

Tags: linux, bash, email

I am working on writing a script to run on our Debian server(`Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u5 x86_64 GNU/Linux`), which will monitor a specific port we have and when there is no process running on that port, or that port is available, then I will have to send out an email. I intend to run the script every 15 minutes and then send out an email.

We have an email-server and I want to add it's configuration in the script, but I am not sure how I can do that.

When in Java, I am using the configuration in this manner :

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "EMAIL-HOST-NAME");
props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "PORT-PROVIDED");
```

Currently, I have the script as follows, any suggestions to script are also welcome. Thank you.

```
#!/bin/bash

server=0.0.0.0 // localhost
port=PORT-NUMBER

  if nc $server $port &> /dev/null; then
       // do nothing
    else
       // send email 
  fi
```

Thank you.

Comment: You want to store output of `PORT-NUMBER` in `port`?, if so it should be `port=${PORT-NUMBER}`

Comment: @Inian : I will add that change, wouldn't a hard-coded value like 1234 directly work?

Comment: Something like `port=1234` should work too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `mailx` and `sendmail` can send full e-mails from CLI; most systems feature both preinstalled.

Example with 'mailx':

```
echo "This is the message body and contains the message" | mailx -v \
-r "someone@example.com" \
-s "This is the subject" \
-S smtp="mail.example.com:587" \
-S smtp-use-starttls \
-S smtp-auth=login \
-S smtp-auth-user="someone@example.com" \
-S smtp-auth-password="abc123" \
-S ssl-verify=ignore \
yourfriend@gmail.com
```